# Windows 8 doesn't appear in the bootloader after installing Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: grub2, bootloader

On my windows 8 PC I installed ubuntu 13.04 through USB. After that no option to select Windows 8 was in the bootloader. How can I add Windows 8 to the bootloader?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo update-grub`? That should look for all of the installed operating systems on your hard disk and make them selectable from the grub bootloader. Also as noted below you can install Grub Customizer for a GUI and some better options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: @EliahKagan No, this is when Windows doesn't even appear... nothing about selecting.. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @EliahKagan Well as far as I understand that's exactly what that question deals with... :S

Comment: @Seth The problem in [that question](http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/22949) is that *only Windows can be booted.* The problem in this question is that *only Ubuntu can be booted.* The cause of the problem in that question is that GRUB has been overwritten by the Windows boot loader in the MBR. More generally, when GRUB needs to be *reinstalled* to the MBR *and Ubuntu does not boot at all*, we send people to that question. In *this* question, GRUB is in the MBR, and Ubuntu boots; the problem is that for some reason `os-prober` has not found and configured the Windows system. Totally different.

Comment: If it is a Windows 8 computer pre-installed it has UEFI not BIOS & MBR partitioning.   The os-prober only finds BIOS installs and just recently was updated to find efi installs, but that version in not in many grub2 installs yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install GRUB Customizer. Not simple to use, but it may help, and it's better than editing the Bootloader menu by hand :)

To download, open Software Center and search for grub customiser. Install this programme the when you run it, you will be presented with:

[image: GRUB Customiser]

I do not have Windows, so I do not know what you need to add, but this should be a start.

Comment: It might be more helpful if you provide specific instructions on the download and installation of GRUB Customizer and its use.

Comment: @maggotbrain added as much as I could, but I do not have Windows installed, so have no idea what commands need adding.

Comment: Cool. I'm not sure what Windows has to do with your specific answer. Your answer happened to show up in the low quality post queue and was just suggesting how you might improve your response. Screencaps are always good. ;-)Cheers.